# Golang accessing elements of Gin.H

Tags: go, go-gin

trying out the [example](https://github.com/gin-gonic/examples/tree/master/realtime-advanced) to find out if the it can be a pubsub, I wonder if it is possible to parse or access the elements in gin.H map. I want to send a Json in a POST.

roomPOST() @ route.go

```
    ...
    post := gin.H{
        "message": "{\"12345\":\"on\",\"23456\":\"off\",}",
    }
    ...
```

And I wish to do something with it in streamRoom()

streamRoom() @ route.go

```
    ...
    c.Stream(func(w io.Writer) bool {
        select {
        case msg := <-listener:
            ...
            fmt.Printf("msg: %s %s\n", reflect.TypeOf(msg), msg)
            ...
    }
```

```
msg: gin.H map[message:{"12345":"on","23456":"off"}]
```

When trying to access the element in msg, e.g.

```
element := msg["message"].(string)
```

it throws:

```
invalid operation: cannot index msg (variable of type interface{})
```

Please advise how I can access the elements of Gin.H.

Answer (score 1):

> I wonder if it is possible to parse or access the elements in gin.H map

[`gin.H`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/gin-gonic/gin#H) is defined as `type H map[string]interface{}`. You can index it just like a map.

In your code, `msg` is an `interface{}` whose dynamic type is `gin.H`, as seen from the output of `reflect.TypeOf`, so you can't index it directly. Type-assert it *and then* index it:

```
content := msg.(gin.H)["message"]
```